# Paging scroll View moving vertically to

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

my paging scroll view is moving either horizontally and vertically and it should move only horizontally. I made an application which consists of 2 view the paging scroll view is a subview of one of them which frame is 320*400. my paging scroll view is 320*360 frame.i thought that it will move only horizontally. I pasted part of my code:

```
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f);
        pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
        pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        pagingScrollView.contentSize = [self contentSizeForPagingScrollView];
        pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
        self.view = pagingScrollView;
...
    - (CGSize)contentSizeForPagingScrollView {
        CGRect bounds = pagingScrollView.bounds;
        return CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * [self imageCount], bounds.size.height);
    }
...
    - (NSUInteger)imageCount {
        static NSUInteger __count = NSNotFound;  
        if (__count == NSNotFound) {
            __count = ([rootArray count]/5);
        }

        return __count;
    }
```

thanks

Comment: Is this a cocoac-touch (iOS) or a cocoa (Mac OS X) question? You used the Cocoa tag, but UIKit is not available on Mac OS X so I think this is an iOS question. Please retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
pagingScrollViewFrame.scrollsToTop=NO;
```

Hope it will help

Comment: nearly pagingScrollView.scrollsToTop=NO; i have discovered that in contentSizeForPagingScrollView the bounds.size.height gives me back 480, and i need 360 so i just change it and it work but thx for the answer